# Hilt retrofit injection from multi module app

Tags: android, retrofit2, dagger-hilt

i am trying to create a project which contains utils like RetrofitBuilder and AnalyticsUtil in an android studio module (this will be used across multiple projects)
while the app module contains the actual project.

right now i have my RetrofitBuilder set up as the following

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object RetrofitBuilder {

private const val baseUrl: String = BuildConfig.SERVER_URL

@Singleton
@Provides
fun providesHttpLoggingInterceptor() = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
    .apply {
        level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
        level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.HEADERS
    }

@Singleton
@Provides
fun providesNetworkInterceptor(): Interceptor {
    return Interceptor { chain ->
        val builder = chain.request().newBuilder()
        val defaultHeaders: MutableMap<String, String> = mutableMapOf(
            Pair("Authorization", "Bearer ${BuildConfig.API_KEY}"),
            Pair("Content-Type", "application/json")
        )
        for (header in defaultHeaders) {
            builder.addHeader(header.key, header.value)
        }

        val request = builder.build()
        chain.proceed(request)
    }
}

@Singleton
@Provides
fun providesOkHttpClient(
    networkInterceptor: Interceptor,
    httpLoggingInterceptor: HttpLoggingInterceptor
): OkHttpClient =
    OkHttpClient
        .Builder()
        .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .addNetworkInterceptor(networkInterceptor)
        .addInterceptor(httpLoggingInterceptor)
        .build()

@Singleton
@Provides
fun provideRetrofit(okHttpClient: OkHttpClient): Retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
    .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create())
    .baseUrl(baseUrl)
    .client(okHttpClient)
    .build()
```

}

and here's the code starting from the activity to the service

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
}
}
```

fragment

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class ComingSoonFragment : Fragment() {

private val comingSoonViewModel: ComingSoonViewModel by viewModels()
private var _binding: FragmentComingSoonBinding? = null
private val binding get() = _binding!!

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View {
    _binding = FragmentComingSoonBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
    return binding.root
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    comingSoonViewModel.getComingSoon()
}

}
```

viewmodel

```
@HiltViewModel
class ComingSoonViewModel @Inject constructor(
val comingSoonRepository: ComingSoonRepository
) : ViewModel() {

fun getComingSoon() {
    comingSoonRepository.getComingSoon()
}

}
```

service

```
interface ComingSoonService {

@GET("movie/upcoming")
fun getComingSoon(): Call<Upcoming>
}
```

now note that RetrofitBuilder is located in a module named "skeleton" while the rest of the code is in the "app" module as any normal project, this is the error i get when hilt tries to inject retrofit

```
error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] retrofit2.Retrofit cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or an @Provides-annotated method.
public abstract static class SingletonC implements BOTApplication_GeneratedInjector,
                     ^
  retrofit2.Retrofit
```

here's how the repo/service are provided

```
@Module
InstallIn(ViewModelComponent::class)
object ComingSoonViewModelModule {
@Provides
@ViewModelScoped
fun provideComingSoonRepository(comingSoonService: 
ComingSoonService) =
    ComingSoonRepository(comingSoonService)

@Provides
@ViewModelScoped
fun provideComingSoonService(retrofit: Retrofit): 
ComingSoonService = 
retrofit.create(ComingSoonService::class.java)
}
```

any idea about fixing this?

Comment: Where is your repository(ComingSoonRepository) code?

Comment: it's in question, so far it has no business logic its just a simple function calling the one in the service

Comment: is this possible for you to provide GitHub repo link? just wanted to connect the dots.

Comment: I think you are not providing service from your RetrofitBuilder.

Comment: yes the service is in the app module and not the skeleton module, right now i tried copying the retrofitbuilder to the app module and it worked fine, so i guess im missing something there

Comment: please show your build.gradle... and `ComingSoonRepository`

Comment: how have you added or exposed your module dependency in your :apps modules. Is it via api or implementation?

Comment: it might be possible if you have not exposed them to your :app module, your app-moudle isnt able to reach the genetated dagger graph in your network module, as your app module contains @HiltApp in your application.

Comment: @ritesh i haven't did any sort of linking, didn't know i need to

Comment: so all your code including dagger/hilt setup are in one single module?

Comment: Also, as others metioned - please show your ComingSoonRepository, how it's provided - i am assuming its constructor injected.

Comment: Are you running the Dagger processor over `:skeleton`?

Comment: apologies for the delay, i edited the question to include how the repo/service are provided, and @Nitrodon by running the dagger processor i'm guessing u mean adding dependencies and so on? yes i do have it there

Comment: @MahmoudOmara : were you able to resolve this issue ?

Comment: @Ritt Can you please on this. We are following the structure

Comment: no this was not resolved, since it's a side project for fun only i decided to go single module route and then figure this out later for now